# jQuery .load() Not Sending HTML Tags

Tags: php, jquery

I have a dynamic PHP table (tableData.php) that I need to import onto my main page (index.php). I'm using jQuery .load() to import the data, and that's working fine. The table is appended to the div that I want it in.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#newTable").load("tableData.php");
```

Once tableData.php is rendered on my main page, I then need to then do things with that table. So if a user clicks on a < TD >, certain functions fire.

```
$('td').on('click', (this), function() {
var time = $(this).closest("table").attr("id");
```

The problem is that .load() isn't sending the HTML elements to my main page so jQuery isn't recognizing that a < TD > has been clicked. Viewing the page source, it just shows an empty div where the new table sits. If I use 
    < ? php include 'tableData.php'; ?> it works great, but I want this table to render after the page has loaded.

My question is, is there a way to copy the actual HTML of one page into another page? Right now it seems that I just have a shallow copy, when I need a deep copy.

Comment: If the PHP file returns HTML, `load` definitely creates those elements. But those elements didn't exist when you did `$('td').on('click', ...)`, so they don't have the event handler on them. See the linked question's answers for what to do about that. Also note that "view source" does not show you the current DOM, it shows you what the server originally sent (actually, usually it re-requests the page and shows you the current result). If you want to see the current state of the DOM, don't use "view source," use "inspect element" and the DOM/Elements panel in your browser's devtools.

Comment: $(document).on('click', 'td', function() {    Thank you. I changed my click function to bind to the document itself, and now it's working.